# How to remove jquery cache on hovered item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i'm not sure if i gave the right term. I'm having an issue on how to remove the cache on the hovered item.

**Html**

```
<div class="gallery-nav">
<ul>
    <li> <a href="#" class="jan">01</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#" class="feb">02</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#" class="march">03</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#" class="april">04</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#" class="may">05</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#" class="june">06</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#" class="july">07</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#" class="aug">08</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#" class="sept">09</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#" class="oct">10</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#" class="nov">11</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#" class="dec">12</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function growLine(e) {
e.find('span').stop(false,true).animate({
    width: 22
}, 400);
}

function shrinkLine(e) {
    e.find('span').stop(false,true).animate({
    width: 0
    }, 400);
}

$('.gallery-nav li').each(function() {
    $(this).append('<span />');
});

$('.gallery-nav li:first-child').addClass('active');

$('.gallery-nav li').hover(function() {
    if( !$(this).hasClass('active') ) {
        growLine($(this) );
    }
}, function() {
    if( !$(this).hasClass('active') ) {
        shrinkLine( $(this) ); 
    }
});

$('.gallery-nav li a').click( function () {

    var allList = $('.gallery-nav li');
    var e =  $(this);

    allList.removeAttr('class');
    e.parent().addClass('active');

});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swqo9dn4/)

There is a line below the numbers when hovered.
The problem is the line is not removed once i click on other numbers.
This works but only once.

Comment: Add your code here at SO. Didn't you get the warning message.

Comment: hi @Satpal here is fiddle link for my code http://jsfiddle.net/swqo9dn4/

Comment: @Satpal  you may click the link above this comment

Comment: You are not getting the point SO is would-be self-contained knowledge base and people should not go offsite to help. Links rot, the question will be useless for future users in that case.

Comment: Yes @Satpal is right, you must add a code / html that you have tried so far because the shared link may lost in future. Though I added my answer I am deleting it if you don't edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing animation to set width of `span`(which is inside `li`) equal to `width=22` and adding class`active` to `li`. You just have to revert this effect.
You need to modify your click event handler so that to set `width=0px` for `span` and `active` class from the `li` having `class="active"`, see below code

```
$('.gallery-nav li a').click( function () {
   var e =  $(this);
   $('li.active').find('span').css('width','0px');  
   $('li.active').removeClass('active');
   e.parent().addClass('active');
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/swqo9dn4/6/)**

Answer (score 0):

try this: [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swqo9dn4/8/)

```js
    $('.gallery-nav li:first-child').addClass('active');
 $('.gallery-nav li').click( function () {
         $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
 });
```

```css
.gallery-nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 ;
    list-style: none;
} 

.gallery-nav li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 7px;
}

.gallery-nav li a {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font: 300 19px 'Lato', sans-serif; 
    color : #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.gallery-nav li a:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -2px;
    left: 0;
    background: red;
    height: 1px;
    width: 0px;
    transition: width .3s ease 
}

.gallery-nav li.active > a,
.gallery-nav li:hover > a {
    font-weight: 700;
}
.gallery-nav li:hover a:before,
.gallery-nav li.active a:before {
    width: 22px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gallery-nav">
    <ul>
        <li> <a href="#" class="jan">01</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#" class="feb">02</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#" class="march">03</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#" class="april">04</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#" class="may">05</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#" class="june">06</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#" class="july">07</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#" class="aug">08</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#" class="sept">09</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#" class="oct">10</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#" class="nov">11</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#" class="dec">12</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```